# Chain rule for function of two derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Let $u = f(x, y)$ be a $C^2$-function. Let $x = rcos\theta$ and $y = rsin\theta$. Compute $\frac {d^2u}{dr^2}$ in terms of partial derivatives.

Answer: $\frac {d^2u}{dr^2}$ = $\frac {d}{dr}$($\frac {du}{dr}$) = $\frac {d}{dr}$ ($\frac {df}{dx}$$cos\theta$ + $\frac {df}{dy}$$sin\theta$) = ($\frac {d^2f}{dx^2}$ $\frac {dx}{dr}$ + $\frac {d^2f}{dy~~dx}$ $\frac {dy}{dr}$)$cos\theta$ + ($\frac {d^2f}{dx~~dy}$ $\frac {dx}{dr}$ + $\frac {d^2f}{dy^2}$ $\frac {dy}{dr}$)$sin\theta$

I don't get how you go from the third step to the last step in the answer. Can someone please explain how this works? Do you use the distributive law in this case?

Comment: For the last step, I believe you may switch the order of derivation.  Thus you calculate
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\cos\theta\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\sin\theta\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}
$$

Comment: @FrankMcGovern: Thanks!